# How do I install amdgpu-pro in ubuntu 16.04 LTS with a 400 series card?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, amd-graphics

I have a 460 and I am having trouble with installing the driver for it I looked at the tutorial that amd gave me and im stuck on the part where is says "run the included script (amdgpu-pro-install)" I don't know what script they mean, here is the website. http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx please excuse me if it was an easy thing to do im new to Linux.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com! Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask It's inefficient to have to scroll through numerous comments just to determine what your problem is. Thank you for helping us help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tells you what to do if you read the next few sentences:

> The script will use the package manager to install the components of the graphics stack, with a short delay during the DKMS (Dynamic Kernel Module Support) installation. From the directory where you extracted the archive, issue the following command:
>
> ```
> amdgpu-pro-driver/amdgpu-pro-install
> ```

But it turns out these instructions are more than a little misleading and confusing.

Instead of following them, follow these:

1. Download the driver. At the time of this answer, the filename is `amdgpu-pro-16.40-348864.tar.xz`, **but this will change.**
2. Extract the driver.

   - Enter the directory where you downloaded the driver file (default is `~/Downloads`). Use `cd dirname`, where `dirname` is the name of the directory.
   - Use the command `tar -Jxvf filename` to extract the driver in the current directory. `filename` is the name of the name of the driver file downloaded.
3. Install the driver.

   - In the same directory, run `cd foldername`. `foldername` is the name of the folder that was created when the driver file was extracted. It should begin with `amdgpu`, so type `cd amdgpu` and then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> so that it completes the folder name
4. Reboot.

   - Once the terminal returns to a prompt, restart the computer. AMDGPU-PRO will now be installed.

Comment: Wait I entered the downloads directory but when I enter in amdgpu-pro-driver/amdgpu-pro-install it says no such file or directory

Comment: @TjSumair did you run the extraction command?

Comment: Yea I did it had an error and said tar (child): amdgpu-pro_16.40-348864.tar.xz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
 so i extracted from the folder

Comment: @TjSumair run the command, making sure the terminal is in the correct directory, and use tab complete to fill in the file name. Type amdgpu and then press tab.

Comment: Same thing happened.

Comment: You've `cd`ed to where you downloaded `amdgpu-pro-16.40-348864.tar.xz` and you've run `tar -Jxvf amdgpu-pro_16.30.3-315407.tar.xz`? Only `cd /tmp` if you actually downloaded the archive there.

Comment: Yea I did go to the directory and ran the command I changed the file name to what the file acutall is named and I showed you what happened so I tried -Jxvf amdgpu-pro_16.30.3-315407.tar.xz and it says-Jxvf: command not found.

Comment: The command is `tar -Jxvf`, not just `-Jxvf`.

Comment: This is what happened when I entered in that

Comment: ~/Downloads$ tar -Jxvf amdgpu-pro_16.30.3-315407.tar.xz
\tar (child): amdgpu-pro_16.30.3-315407.tar.xz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Are  you absolutely sure the file is in Downloads?

Comment: Yes I am sure when I hit donwloads  it shows the tar.xz file.

Comment: I see the issue. Don't copy and paste the command. Use tab complete after typing `amdgpu` to get the correct filename.

Comment: Ok so that worked but now what do I do next? I pasted amdgpu-pro-driver/amdgpu-pro-install
 and it says no such file or directory.

Comment: Use `cd amdgpu-pro-16.40-348864` and then `./amdgpu-pro-install`

Comment: Ok so it finished I assuming update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-47-generic then last thing it says is ~/Downloads/amdgpu-pro-16.40-348864$ should I restart now? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, reboot now.

Comment: Ok I rebooted Im already in the video group and the res is kinda wonky im on a tv screen right now should I be fine when I get my monitor? Thank you so much btw I have been stuck on this problem for a few weeks now.

Comment: I've never used AMDGPU-PRO, so I can't tell you how well it's going to work for you. Hopefully, it'll get better, but I just don't know.