# Ubuntu (16.04) Black Screen On Boot After Installing AMDGPU-PRO Driver?

Tags: boot, 16.04, drivers, amdgpu

Basically I want better FPS and graphics by utilizing my actual GPU, which apparently I haven't actually been doing. So I did my research and stumbled upon http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Install.aspx. I ended up installing the driver perfectly with no errors or any problems but upon reboot, I will maybe get the GRUB menu only 1 out of 5 reboots of my PC and when I do and choose Ubuntu, it just gets stuck on a black screen, no text no cursor nothing. I can get back in by going into recovery mode and uninstalling the driver, but I really want to be able to utilize it with my PC and make it work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And your GPU model is? Few things: The AMDGPU-Pro driver is BETA and far from finished. Depending on your GPU, it might be a better call to install the Radeon/fglrx drivers, but there are several problems to do so in 16.04, so you might need to downgrade or upgrade.

Comment: My GPU is a Radeon RX 460 which says it is compatible but idk.

Comment: here you find an accepted answer to your problem: https://askubuntu.com/questions/848312/how-do-i-install-amdgpu-pro-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts-with-a-400-series-card good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to uninstall AMDGPU?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117883/how-to-uninstall-amdgpu) and [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 14.04.5/16.04 and newer on AMD graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815591/ubuntu-14-04-5-16-04-and-newer-on-amd-graphics)